# Encourage followed be "possessive pronoun + gerund"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Are these grammatically acceptable?

1 He encouraged my working hard. (always)

2 He encouraged me to work hard. (always or one-off occurrence)

Is this wrong?

3 He encouraged my applying for the visa. (wrong - because it's only a one-off occasion)

Comment: "Encourage" takes both infinitival and gerund-participial complements. Both genitive and non-genitive forms are permitted in the latter, with the genitive as usual being more formal.

Comment: Do you see the difference which comes down to the following: encourage someone to do smth - means a one-off action, encourage someone's doing something - means on a regular basis.

Comment: No, and there is nothing wrong with your example 3.